# Mongoose alter the result of create()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to create a new document in a collection, using a Mongoose model. The function returns the object if it has been created in the collection. As of right now, it returns all fields of the object, including the password (which is an object with hash and salt attributes).

I know that you can use Model.find({...}, '-field') to omit a field from the result when using the find commands, but is there any way to do this with the result given from a create() command? I have tried setting the password field to select: false, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is [not supported](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6300).

You can either:

1. Take only the ID from `create()` result and issue a fresh `findById()` call (which *does* respect select:false). [OR]
2. Manipulate the `create()` result to hide the field.